# boosted regression trees train error in caret package

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to use the code below to train a boosted regression tree by CV of AUC.
But I am getting the message:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "subscript out of bounds"
```

If I didn't specify distribution="gaussian", I will not receive the error message.

Any ideal to fix this problem? Thank you very much.

```
 gbmGrid <- expand.grid(interaction.depth=(3:6), n.trees=(1:40)*100, shrinkage=.01)
 gbmGrid$n.minobsinnode = rep(10,nrow(gbmGrid))
 head(gbmGrid)

 bootControl <- trainControl(method='cv',classProbs = TRUE,number=3,summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

 gmbFit<- caret::train(X,Y,
                  distribution="gaussian",
                  method = "gbm", 
                  verbose = F, 
                  trControl = bootControl, 
                  bag.fraction=0.5,
                  metric="ROC",
                  tuneGrid=gbmGrid)
```

Comment: This is not reproducible. I ran your code with the `iris` dataset and did not get this message.

Comment: Please, don't use inappropriate tags -- boost is about [Boost C++ libraries](http://www.boost.org).

Comment: which variable is your response variable when you run `iris` dataset? Because I want the function return the "probability". For my case, the response variable have two class, 0(not default loan) and 1 (default loan). I want to calculate the probability of default loan.

I guess maybe I should change the response variable to a numeric variable?

Comment: These are the code I use for produce X and Y. `index = sample(1:nrow(sample_set[[i]]), floor(nrow(sample_set[[i]])/10), replace=FALSE)
     train = sample_set[[i]][index,]
     test = sample_set[[i]][-index,]
     train$def_flag = as.factor(as.logical(train$def_flag))
     test$def_flag = as.factor(as.logical(test$def_flag))

      X = train[,-8]
      Y = train[,8]
      Y = as.numeric(Y)
      Y[which(Y==1)] = 'no'
      Y[which(Y==2)] = 'yes'`